# How does ISurface.Locate work?

Tags: arcobjects

could someone help me with this method of arcobjects? I don't know what the parameter "hint" means. Thanks.

[ISurface.Locate](http://help.arcgis.com/en/sdk/10.0/arcobjects_net/componenthelp/index.html#//00250000088m000000) Method
Returns the intersection of the query ray and the displayed feature.
[Visual Basic 6.0]
Function Locate(
    ByVal pRay As IRay, _
    ByVal hint As Long _
) As IPoint

Parameters
pRay [in]
  pRay is a parameter of type IRay
hint [in]
  hint is a parameter of type long
ppLocation [out, retval]
  ppLocation is a parameter of type IPoint

Comment: I'd try passing 0 as the `hint` argument. If that works, try passing different values and examine whether the result differs. Chances are this argument is reserved for future use and has no effect at all.